# How can I get or create my app level client id in Huawei for any kit?

Tags: android, huawei-mobile-services, agconnect-functions

I wish to develop an application and need to release in AppGallery. What is client id in Huawei, and How can I get or create my app level client id in Huawei?
I am looking forward your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an OAuth 2.0 client ID on the API console of HUAWEI Developers, use the client ID to integrate Account Kit for your app, generate an access token, and call Huawei public APIs to access resources authorized by users.

If you have generated a client ID (for example, a client ID for a phone or smart display app), you can use the client ID to implement integration in multiple scenarios without performing any operation in this section.
For example, if John (a developer) has obtained APPID-1 (a client ID) for his mobile app and already has Account Kit integrated, he can directly use this ID for his new web app to complete the integration of Account Kit.

If you create an app in AppGallery Connect , set client_id and client_secret to the client ID and client secret that you get after the app is created.

[image]